# Will the finally block to be reached if there is "Where (true)" block in try block?

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

Here's the code puzzled me:

```
public Integer getInteger(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
    boolean interrupted = false;
    try {
        while (true) {
            try {
                return queue.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                interrupted = true;
                // fall through and retry
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (interrupted)
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

It seems like the try block would not stop because of the *While(true)* block, but I was told that finally block will always be executed after the try block ends. So When will the finally block execute?

Comment: I don't think you will reach the `finally` block if you really have an infinite loop in the `try` block.

Answer (score 4):

when there's another exception that does not derive from InterruptedException

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I have the feeling he should rework his logic to not depend on an exception for the program to advance.

Comment: Or when there is a no-exception `queue.take()` causing a return.

Answer (score 4):

The `finally` block will execute when the `try` block completes, which in your case can be for two reasons:

- `queue.take()` completes normally, which means it returns a value, which causes the `return` statement to complete normally, and return from the method with the value from `take()`.
- `queue.take()` completes abruptly by throwing an `Exception` (or `Error`) other than `InterruptedException`.

Abbreviated quote of Java Language Specification "[Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)":

> - If execution of the try block **completes normally**, then the **finally block is executed** *[...]*
> - If execution of the try block **completes abruptly** because of a throw of a value V, then there is a choice:
>
>   - If the run-time type of V is assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any catch clause *[...]* Then there is a choice:
>
>     - If the catch block completes normally, then the **finally block is executed** *[...]*
>     - If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the **finally block is executed** *[...]*
>   - If the run-time type of V is not assignment compatible with a catchable exception class of any catch clause of the try statement, then the **finally block is executed** *[...]*
> - If execution of the try block completes abruptly for any other reason R, then the **finally block is executed** *[...]*

All paths lead to "finally block is executed".

In short, the `finally` block is *always* executed when the `try` block completes, for whatever reason. The only way for that not to happen, is an abnormal termination of the JVM (e.g. JVM kill, JVM crash, OS crash, or power loss).